# Rails Not Reading a Specific Column from CSV

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to read my CSV file in Rails 5.2.3 (Ruby 2.6.3) and it's not reading a specific column.

CSV file:

```
barcode,hardware,title,price
2900007868390,PS4,title1,300
3499550362923,PS4,title2,1800
3499550370973,Nintendo Switch,title3,5000

and so on...
```

Code:

```rb
csv = CSV.read('path/to/my_csv.csv', headers: true)
csv.each do |row|
  puts "#{row['barcode']}, #{row['hardware']}, #{row['title']}, #{row['price']}"
end
```

Result:

```rb
, PS4, title1, 300
, PS4, title2, 1800
, Nintendo Switch, title3, 5000

and so on...
```

As you can see above, it's not reading the barcode column for some reason.
I've managed to get the barcode value if I write `row[0]` instead of `row['barcode']` .
Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: what do you get if you do `puts row.keys` inside your `.each`  loop?

Comment: I got: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'keys' for #<CSV::Row:0x0000557fb75c93b0>`

Comment: WEIRD!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: possibly because `row` is technically not a hash. What if you do `row.to_h.keys`?

Comment: I got the desired results; `barcode` , `hardware` , `title` , `price` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was because my CSV file had BOMs...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

The code below solved the problem:

```rb
csv = CSV.read("resources/games/original_#{date}.csv", 'r:BOM|UTF-8', headers: true)
```

Thank you @dimitry_n for your help!

Comment: An age-old Windows evil, I guess. By the way, you can accept your own answer for other people to easily find the solution.